# Get unique data pair from table join

Tags: sqlite, join, duplicates

I'm trying to make a matching program in SQL where it output the following data

- Shared street
- Shared pet
- Person 1 favorite food
- Person 2 favorite food

The People table have a distinct timestamp column

I wrote

```sql
Create Table match As
  Select a.street, a.pet, a.food, b.food
  From People a, People b
  Where a.street = b.street And a.pet = b.pet And a.time <> b.time
  Order by a.time;
```

Example table

| Street | Pet | Food | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| maple | dog | pizza | 2021/07/28 12:55:56 PM MDT |
| maple | cat | pizza | 2021/07/28 3:34:56 PM MDT |
| maple | dog | french fries | 2021/07/28 12:34:56 PM MDT |
| abney | dog | pizza | 2021/07/28 5:34:56 PM MDT |
| abney | cat | pizza | 2021/07/28 12:45:56 PM MDT |
| abney | dog | french fries | 2021/07/28 2:34:56 PM MDT |

For example it outputs this

```
maple|dog|pizza|french fries
maple|dog|french fries|pizza (duplicate)
abney|dog|pizza|french fries
abney|dog|french fries|pizza (duplicate)
```

How can I make it so it doesn't return duplicate value?

Edit: I might not want to use "Distinct" since there are a lot of non-duplicate values that can be flagged as duplicate (since its the same output but from different people)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the operator `<>` use `>` (or `<`) to compare the `time`s.
Also use a proper join with an `ON` clause:

```
SELECT p1.street, p1.pet, p1.food, p2.food
FROM People p1 INNER JOIN People p2
ON p2.street = p1.street AND p2.pet = p1.pet AND p2.time > p1.time
ORDER BY p1.time;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=043cc432c68f4d7bb1173f8deb726b9f).

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem perfectly! I thought without join itd still work but i was wrong

Comment: @Enderhoang the syntax with the `,` between the table names you use is actually the old style of a CROSS join.

Comment: Thanks for this knowledge! Im new to SQL and just started about several days ago, still learning the basic of it